# Image upload form in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

Any idea why this doesn't work when I click the `<button>` but does when I click the `<input>` tag? Using ReactJS.

Also, if I got the button working `this.uploadFile` wouldn't have access to the file from the `<input>` tag.

```
<form className="" onSubmit={this.uploadFile}>
  <div className="img-wrapper">
    <UserAvatar userId={ currentUser._id } imageId={ currentUser.profile.picture } size="small" fSize="small" shape="circle" />
    <input type="file" name="avatar" ref="imageInput" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"  multiple="false" />
    <button type="submit" className="">Edit pic</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No error, just not working. The <button> submit isn't triggering onSubmit={this.uploadFile} in the <form> tag.

Comment: have you bind(this) the function?.. or in ES7 syntax `::this.uploadFile`

Comment: When I say not working I mean the <button> tag isn't working, but the <input> and <form> does work so it's not a .bind() issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<div className="img-wrapper">
  <UserAvatar userId={ currentUser._id } imageId={ currentUser.profile.picture } size="small" fSize="small" shape="circle" />
  <input type="file" name="avatar" onChange={ this.uploadFile } ref="imageInput" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"  multiple="false" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's what you/we originally had, but I also want it to open/upload file when I click on some text, next to the actual picture, i.e. "Click to change picture.".